# Laravel - Eloquent way to connect three tables using two pivots

Tags: php, laravel, join, pivot

New to laravel,

I have three tables `users`, `roles`, and `permissions`. Those are connected with the following two pivot tables `role_user`, and `permission_role`

Here I want to connect three tables so I can get a result like **many-to-many** and **one-to-many** relationship. For instance, I can get all permissions and roles for the given user (one-to-many) and vise-versa for roles and permissions to each other. Also, I want to get all users and respective roles and permissions and vise-versa for roles and permissions.

I have just solved the issue getting roles for the given user with the help of the community but now I stuck to get the above mention result. Can anyone help me to make it happen?

### DB Diagram

[image]

### User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role');
    }
}
```

### Role Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'display'];

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Permission');
    }

    public function admin_users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Admin');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

## Permission Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['model', 'can'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role');
    }
}
```

Comment: sample of data you want to fetch

Comment: I want to fetch user fields along with roles and permission fields.

Comment: you can't do it by User::with('roles', 'permission')->find(id); ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 getting error `Call to undefined relationship [permissions] on model [App\Admin\Admin].`

Comment: @Qonvex620 Finally I found a solution. It is something similar to this one https://laravel.io/forum/02-09-2016-how-to-return-information-from-a-third-table I will add code as an answer so other can refer it. Thanks a lot for hint that provided direction.

Comment: then you have to use hasManythrough for that

Comment: or else you could use this,  User::with('roles.permission')->find(id)

Comment: What hasManythrough does? and how it works?

Comment: if you want to access the permission of the user, you could create a relationship in your user model with permission using hasManyThrough

Comment: @Qonvex620 impressive, if you don't mind can you provide a doc link so can refer it? Meantime I am trying myself.

Comment: Sorry, hasManyTrough is applicable on three tables which relations are hasMany only. In your case you have a relation that is belongsTomany.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to @ He provides a direction.

So here `with()` I had to add the `roles` model to call the `permissions` method from it. So the code will look like below.

```
User::with('roles', 'roles.permissions')->find($id);
```

So here `roles.permissions` is the `permissions()` method in `Role` model

## Role Model

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'display'];

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Permission');
    }

    ...
}
```